# SVN (Subversive in Eclipse) - compare branch to trunk?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I used to work with CVS where it was no problem to compare HEAD to any branch, branch to branch or branch to HEAD. Now on SVN I have some changes on trunk I need to put on a branch, but can't seem to find an option to compare given branch to trunk.

Is it possible to have a branch project in workspace and compare it to trunk?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

right-click on the project and choose `Compare With`, `Branch/Tag` (this is with subclipse)

[image]

#### APPENDED

What version of the svn client are you using?  When I open the Compare With dialog on a project checked out from branch it lets me enter any URL (including trunk) and any revision to compare it to.

[image]

Comment: Note that I want to compare branch to trunk, not vice versa. What you're suggesting as solution only enables me to compare branch to another branch.

Comment: shouldn't matter, branches/tags/trunk are just folder names in SVN so should be able to compare anything to anything

Comment: yeah, but I only get the list of branches when I use "compare with > branch/tag", no mention of trunk

Comment: I added another screenshot of the compare dialog, should let you compare to anything at any revision

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out first thing tomorrow morning at work.

Comment: It works, in Subversive it's Compare to Revision/URL and then check HEAD revision .

Comment: This answer is also useful for people searching for Git compare operations on Eclipse.  And for anyone Searching for a Simple Code Review solution that does not involve installing additional tools.